# How can I turn the results of a stored procedure into a comma-separated list in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I turn the results of a stored procedure called in asp.net into a comma-separated list?

This list will then be used as a parameter for another stored procedure.

I'm using C#, Visual Studio 2010, asp.net version 4.0, SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm creating batch reports and emailing them out.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectString"].ConnectionString);

con.Open();

using (var command = new SqlCommand("Report_FilterSproc", con)
{
    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
})

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // do something here to convert these results to a comma-separated list.
    }
};

con.Close();
```

Comment: Create a `List` object, add each value to the list, then call `string.Join` passing in your list value and a comma.

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but do you know you can pass a datatable as a parameter into a stored procedure? This would mean you don't need to mess around with comma separated strings. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214492/Passing-a-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure-in-Sql-S

Comment: you should use a using around the `SqlConnection` too.

Comment: Hi Dan - I have to pass the param as a comma separated list b/c i'm querying a dbase snapshot & that is the format it accepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create comma seperated string using `List<string>` and `string.join`

```
        List<string> lstString = new List<string>();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectString"].ConnectionString);

        con.Open();

        using (var command = new SqlCommand("Report_FilterSproc", con))
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    lstString.Add(reader["ColumnName"].ToString());
                    //do something here to convert these results to a comma separated list.
                }
            }
        }

        con.Close();

        string result = string.Join(",", lstString.ToArray());
```

BTW, please use the `SqlCommand` using in the right way.

Comment: What do you mean by use SqlCommand the right way? I'm a dba & don't write alot of code...

Comment: Look the above code, which I have updated with actual 'Using' statement.

Answer (score 0):

One method, use an `ICollection<String>`, built it up then use `String.Join()` to dump it as a CSV:

```
/* ... */
ICollection<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    values.Add(/*reader value*/);
}
String csv = String.Join(",", values);
```

Another options is to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
/*...*/
var builder = new StringBuilder();
while (reader.Read())
{
    builder.Append(builder.Length > 0 "," : "").Append(/*reader value */);
}
String csv = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Was that supposed to be List instead of HashSet?

Comment: @JoeEnos: Nope. No need for the additional overhead. `HashSet<T>` is a little lighter than `List<T>`.

Comment: There was no indication in the question that they wanted an unsorted or unique collection - you lose both the original order and duplicates with a HashSet, which may or may not be important, but I wouldn't assume.

Answer (score -1):

```
SqlConnection con = new 
SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeConnectString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
List<string> lt = new List<string>();
using (var command = new SqlCommand("Report_FilterSproc", con)
{
CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
})
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
while (reader.Read())
{
lt.add(reader.GetString(1));
}
};
con.Close();

doStuff(string.Join<string>(";", lt);
```

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted this without a comment.  It seems pretty similar to the other answers.

Comment: yeah, i've seen it now. the difference is, on the other answer, they're converting the List to an array first, and then calling the Join() function with an array parameter. All I did was use the Join<string>() function that expects a List<string> as parameter, without the need to convert it to array.